# Antonym of Anathema

Tags: antonyms

> His teachings were a __________ to him.

If I use the word **anathema** here, it would mean something that X abhorred very much. But if I were to contrast this sentence, what should I use, the antonym of anathema ?

Comment: Logically, you'd think _athema_. But no.

Comment: 'Delight' seems the obvious answer.

Comment: I think the best ~adjective~ might be "cherished" but that's not a noun...something that you're drawn to cherish ... hmm

Comment: Sometimes we say something "was as draw" for him.  Eample:, "The universities football tradition was a draw for U of ABC with all things being equal between the other schools academically." .. "Draw" is more of a solid attraction while anathema is something that repells immensely and viscerally sickens ... so Draw and Anathema aren't enough on the same scale for me to call it a real answer. ("attraction" could also be a tepid antonym to anathema)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I like delight

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *beatitude* or *euphoria* would work?  Or perhaps *blessing*?  Blessing isn't quite right and I'm not sure that euphoria is the right kind of word to fit in there.  But maybe that will help...?

Comment: I like "blessing." Anathema can mean "[May he be] anathema," meaning may he be cursed or damned. Kind of like "A pox on him!"

Comment: In the Jewish culture, a traditional consolation for someone whose loved one has died is "may his/her memory be a blessing".  I rather like that.

Comment: I rather like that too!  Don

Comment: Quite and https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/anathema suggests blessing, alongside benediction and benison…

Answer (score 1):

His teachings were a __________ to him.

Pleasing to him.

A pleasure for/to him.

Pleasure = you like something and find it pleasurable

Answer (score 0):

**consecration** - a solemn commitment of your life or your time to some cherished purpose 
(to a service or a goal)consecration -  "his consecration to study"
allegiance, commitment, loyalty, dedication - the act of binding yourself (intellectually or emotionally) to a course of action; 
"his long commitment to public service"; "they felt no loyalty to a losing team"

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consecration

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps his teaching were *fundamental* to him, the basic principles by which he believed he should live and make decisions.